# JMeter Multipart JSON Request Form Data

Tags: jmeter, multipartform-data

I am trying to construct a HTTP Request through JMeter that uses a multipart data body.

I have a HTTP Header Manager that has COntent-Type set to multipart/form-data; boundary=AaB03x. I selected 'Use multipart/form-data for POST'.

I then have a data body created as,

```
`-----------------------------AaB03x
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part1"
{"jsonKey1": "JsonValue1" }

-----------------------------AaB03x
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part2"
{ 
  "jsonKey2": "JsonValue2"
}

-----------------------------AaB03x
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="part3"
File Content here!!!!

-----------------------------AaB03x`
```

When I run this, I see that the request doesnt send the body correctly, instead it just sends some random data as,

POST data:

```
--vKOghkU7riRQbaANmmGpMs7j9TxCTUp3S2T0vE--
```

And gives an error response of,

```
`{"errorMsg":"Unable read headers from MultipartStream.","messageCode":"UnableReadHeadersFromMultipartStream","httpStat     us":"BAD_REQUEST","requestName":"RequestName"}`
```

My second question is: 
  the part3 of the request sends a file to upload. Can I pass the file path somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Given you set your own boundary and build your request manually I believe you need to **uncheck** `Use multipart/form-data for POST` in the [HTTP Request Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)
2. If your file encoding isn't very "exotic" you can try using [__FileToString()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) function just instead of `File Content here!!!!`.

---

Looking into [RFC 7578](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7578), it seems you also need a trailing `--` at the end of the last line

Answer (score 0):

You should try sending your JSON data as parameters. Also put your file path in the section for that... And even some servers don't actually need MIME type explicitly declared, you can check yours with some online tool like [this one](http://mime.ritey.com/).

Your HTTP Request could look smethnig like:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to pass separate headers to each of the parts?

Comment: @Dmitrit @Ivan: the problem with this for meis that I cannot modify some of the headers that jMeter populates. For example, I allow jMeter to populate the `'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=ZWOOhTp6nROvG_qX2xFawuP8Y8VG97a0ICnMBy6L; charset=US-ASCII'`. But I dont want the charset to be specified at all. On the other hand, if I define the Content-Type as a header in the Header Manager then the multi-part boundary that I specify is not being used in the request body.